# Navigation controller is nil in the second view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

So I've setup the AppDelegate to load a root view vc which has a navigation controller:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

In my SecondViewController I have a method that then calls a push to present the third view controller:

```
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: thirdVC animated:YES];
```

Although this doesn't work. On closer inspection the self.navigationController property on the SecondViewController is nil. Is there something I've missed on the AppDelegate to make this non-nil?

Comment: try to set the navigation controller separately and init with a view controller, and make it the root view!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this as i was facing same issue but i resolved  it  by setting same class name and Storyboard ID name under The Custom Class header of your project.

registerViewController *regVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registerViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:regVC animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

THere is no need of making the root view controller nil in the app delegate.

Comment: I've tried this and it does't work. What I meant was that the self.navigationController appears to be nil, not sure why.

Comment: r u trying to add navigation controller programmatically to VC or does your VC has navigation controller in storyboard ?@user1686342

Comment: I have no storyboard, I've added programmatically with XIBs

Comment: Hmm I've shared above

Comment: where exactly r u calling the push code in the second VC ?

Comment: r u calling the push code in viewDidload ? or at somepoint where navigation controller is nil ?

Comment: in viewDidLoad the self.navigationController is nil